# Getting std deviation of specific column in a grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a data that I would like to get a std deviation of that particular column then adding the results of it to the original data again.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'patient': [242, 151, 111,122, 342],
        'obs': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'score': ['strong', 'weak', 'weak', 'weak', 'strong']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'obs', 'treatment', 'score'])

df

   patient  obs  treatment   score
0      242    1          0  strong
1      151    2          1    weak
2      111    3          0    weak
3      122    1          1    weak
4      342    2          0  strong
```

So I would like to get std dev of `patient` column which is grouped by `score` column

So the approach I would like have is to **scan through** columns and find `patient` column and check if it is also `numeric`(would like to also adding that in future) and to std deviation calculation and finally add results to the orignial `df`

I tried like this;

```
std_dev_patient = []

for col in df.keys():
        
    df=df.groupby("score")
    
    if df[col]=='patient':
           np.std(col).append(std_dev_patient)
    else:
        pass
    
    df.concat([df,std_dev_patient], axis =1)
    
    df
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Is there a ways to do this process efficiently ?

Thx

## the expected output

```
   patient  obs  treatment   score  std_dev_patient std_dev_obs
0      242    1          0  strong    70.71            ..
1      151    2          1    weak    20.66            ..  
2      111    3          0    weak    20.66            ..
3      122    1          1    weak    20.66            .. 
4      342    2          0  strong    70.71            ..
```

Comment: Can you give your expected outcome Dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Dataframe.groupby.transform`:

```
df['std_dev_patient'] = df.groupby('score')['patient'].transform('std')
print(df)
print(df.select_dtypes(np.number).dtypes)
```

Output:

```
   patient  obs  treatment   score  std_dev_patient
0      242    1          0  strong        70.710678
1      151    2          1    weak        20.663978
2      111    3          0    weak        20.663978
3      122    1          1    weak        20.663978
4      342    2          0  strong        70.710678
```

For `dtype` checking, use `pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes` with `numpy.number`:

```
import numpy as np

g = df.groupby('score')
for c in df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns:
    df['std_dev_%s' % c] = g[c].transform('std')
```

Output:

```
   patient  obs  treatment   score  std_dev_patient  std_dev_obs  \
0      242    1          0  strong        70.710678     0.707107   
1      151    2          1    weak        20.663978     1.000000   
2      111    3          0    weak        20.663978     1.000000   
3      122    1          1    weak        20.663978     1.000000   
4      342    2          0  strong        70.710678     0.707107   

   std_dev_treatment  
0            0.00000  
1            0.57735  
2            0.57735  
3            0.57735  
4            0.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you for loop approach (or what ever is doing conditional check whether the column is also numeric or not and checking its name as in my trial that would be really a solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander Do you want to find which columns are numeric?

Comment: Yes exactly. In the end, I would like to have a pipeline that scan through columns and check that they are numeric or not and if they are numeric do std deviation and and them as new column to df. I edited the expected output to show this.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
df['std_dev_patient'] = df.score.map(df.groupby(by='score').patient.std())
df

    patient obs treatment   score   std_dev_patient
0   242     1   0           strong  70.710678
1   151     2   1           weak    20.663978
2   111     3   0           weak    20.663978
3   122     1   1           weak    20.663978
4   342     2   0           strong  70.710678
```

To calculate std on multiple columns in a for loop manner, just put the desired column names to the std_cols list.

```
std_cols = ['patient', 'obs']

for col in std_cols:
    df[f'std_dev_{col}'] = df.score.map(df.groupby(by='score')[col].std())


patient obs treatment   score   std_dev_patient std_dev_obs
0       242 1       0   strong  70.710678       0.707107
1       151 2       1   weak    20.663978       1.000000
2       111 3       0   weak    20.663978       1.000000
3       122 1       1   weak    20.663978       1.000000
4       342 2       0   strong  70.710678       0.707107
```

To make OP's original for loop solution work:

```
std_dev_patient = []
df_g=df.groupby("score")
df_g=df.groupby("score")
for col in df.keys():
    if col=='patient':
        std_dev_patient.append(df_g[col].std())
    else:
        pass
df['std_dev_patient'] = df.score.map(std_dev_patient[0])

patient obs treatment   score   std_dev_patient
0   242 1   0           strong  70.710678
1   151 2   1           weak    20.663978
2   111 3   0           weak    20.663978
3   122 1   1           weak    20.663978
4   342 2   0           strong  70.710678
```

Comment: Thanks Allen. That's a good solution. Can we do it in a for loop way so I can look up other columns and add their std dev. to the original df. + where is the `score` columns is gone ?

Comment: Just added the score column back. Let me see how I can get a for loop solution work.

Comment: Thanks! Because sometimes we may want to get std dev of another column and just change the variable name in the column and +_std_dev to its name and adding into it to original df. As you did!

Comment: @Alexander, your original for loop solution has a few issues and the reason for that specific error you are seeing is because you assigned the groupby object back to df itself. Please take a look to see if the updated solution meets your need.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Allen for your elegant solution!